# Hibernate query cache applicable for native queries?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have below code snippet  where I am using hibernate query. It works fine. when I fire execute this code second
time query is not fired as it is picked from query cache

```
   Session session = hibernateFactory.openSession();
    Query employeeQuery=session.createQuery("from Employee where employeeId=1");//line 1
    employeeQuery.setCacheable(true);
    Employee employee1=(Employee)employeeQuery.uniqueResult();
    session.close();
```

But as soon as I replace line1 in above code snippet with below line I get exception

```
Query employeeQuery=session.createSQLQuery("select * from Employee where employeeId=1");
```

Execption is

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
at org.hibernate.type.TypeHelper.disassemble(TypeHelper.java:146)
at org.hibernate.cache.StandardQueryCache.put(StandardQueryCache.java:106)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.putResultInQueryCache(Loader.java:2434)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listUsingQueryCache(Loader.java:2321)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2268)
```

Is query cache is not applicable for native queries?

**Update:-** I think Query cache is applicable for HQL not for Native SQL. But in hibernate documentation its not written anywhere. So just wondering am I missing anything here

Comment: Can you give adding scalars a try? From exception it looks as though its failing when converting results to an object.

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html

Comment: But addingScalar is required when i am using column alias and want to specify alias type. If i am not using any aliases , i dont need to mention them right?

Comment: You are right. Hibernate should use `ResultSetMetadata` in this case. But again if SQL queries are not supported in caching Hibernate shouldn't be looking into a cache at the first place. It looks as if it will have to be done with some quirks. Perhaps give scalars a try. What Hibernate version are you using?

Comment: or you can try this workaround / solution described at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25789176/aliases-expected-length-is-0-actual-length-is-1-on-hibernate-query-cache

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLQuery not support cache. It could help you.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_caching.htm

It's better use the hibernate SQL sintaxis.

Comment: i also think Query cache is applicable for HQL not for Native SQL. But in hibernate documentation its not written anywhere :(