# Aliases expected length is 0; actual length is 1 on hibernate query cache

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

```
String q1Str = "SELECT parent_id FROM meta WHERE st_id = "+childIds+";";
Query q1 = em.createNativeQuery(q1Str);
//q1.setHint("org.hibernate.cacheable", true);
Object parentId = null;
try{
parentId = q1.getSingleResult();
}catch(NoResultException nre){
    //nope
}
```

enabling `hibernate.cacheable` will throw me the following exception

> aliases expected length is 0; actual length is 1

Comment: i assume this is a bug in hibernate : https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9111

Comment: hibernate.atlassian.net down for me ( its always down :( ). Mind pasting the information ?

Comment: it works now. if not i can paste content here

Comment: Yeah I saw, we had to rewrite our queries to be named. Did you manage another solution ?

Comment: For me the result set was quite low and we had more than enough memory. So used maps to manage the cache

Comment: @dinesh707  can please tell me, how it is working? what changes you did? I have facing the same issue. Please revert back

Comment: @Kunal we just disabled caching (as shown in code above we are not suing it any more). Instead of caching it in hibernate layer we manually cache it in a LRU map.

Answer (score 1):

So, this happened to me too and after searching / researching a possible solution I've
decided to give up, but after a very long debug session (not Session.class) I stumbled
upon a solution.

And so... The environment

> hibernate-core 5.3.0.Final
>
> Wildfly 20.0.1 Final
>
> Java 11
>
> PostgreSql 9.4 ? (don't know the exact version, sorry)
>
> Infinispan for caching

So, first using

```
em.createNamedQuery("MyClass.findMyStuff", Tuple.class)
            .setParameter(0, declarationDate)
            .setHint("org.hibernate.cacheable", true)
            .getResultList()
```

I received an error similar to this

> aliases expected length is 0; actual length is 1

but, of course, with different numbers (instead of 0 and 1)

Note: my native sql was like this

> select a.date as mydate, a.id as myid, a.test as mytest from mytable a where date = ?0

And so, something smelly hit the fan...

Tried this

```
em.createNamedQuery("MyClass.findMyStuff", Tuple.class)
            .setParameter(0, declarationDate)
            .setHint("org.hibernate.cacheable", true)
            .unwrap(NativeQuery.class)
            .addSynchronizedQuerySpace("myQuery_space")
            .getResultList()
```

and I failed... Tried this same stuff with all addSynchronized methods available in
NativeQuery.class, but each and every time hibernate was telling me to go and fun myself.

Then I tried rewriting my query with HQL, but good luck with that... Rewriting all these
subselects, joins and what not in HQL was just a wishful thinking - NOT POSSIBLE (in my
case. Note that resources I have are limited).

Got back to where I've started... And changed this

```
em.createNamedQuery("MyClass.findMyStuff", Tuple.class)
            .setParameter(0, declarationDate)
            .setHint("org.hibernate.cacheable", true)
            .unwrap(NativeQuery.class)
            .addSynchronizedQuerySpace("myQuery_space")
            .getResultList()
```

to

```
em.createNamedQuery("MyClass.findMyStuff", Tuple.class)
            .setParameter(0, declarationDate)
            .setHint("org.hibernate.cacheable", true)
            .unwrap(NativeQuery.class)
            .addScalar("mydate")
            .getResultList()
```

and got the same error similar to

> aliases expected length is 0; actual length is 1

And then I tried this

```
em.createNamedQuery("MyClass.findMyStuff", Tuple.class)
            .setParameter(0, declarationDate)
            .setHint("org.hibernate.cacheable", true)
            .unwrap(NativeQuery.class)
            .addScalar("mydate", new DateType())
            .getResultList()
```

And BAAAAAAM finally it started working.

To sum it up it started working then I unwrapped query to NativeQuery and added scalar
with a type!!!

Note if your native query does not have aliases then add them!!!

Related threads (to name a few)

> https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9111
>
> [Hibernate Ehcache NOT working for SQL Native query cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40221978/hibernate-ehcache-not-working-for-sql-native-query-cache)
>
> [Hibernate query cache applicable for native queries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15595627/hibernate-query-cache-applicable-for-native-queries)
>
> [Cache JPA Native Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54801806/cache-jpa-native-query)

Answer (score 0):

I think this happens when the queried table does not have a primary key.

Comment: is this the solutions, we are facing same issue,

Comment: As its in the comment in for the qestion, its a bug in hibernate ( not a feature ). https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9111