# Cache JPA Native Query

Tags: caching, java-ee-7, nativequery

PROBLEM: Need to **cache a native query** (Hibernate Query Caching) in a stateless DAO EJB. Hibernate 5.3, Jpa 2.1, JavaEE 7.

RESEARCH:

Working example:

```
getEntityManager().createNativeQuery("SELECT MIN(start_date) FROM report")
  .getSingleResult();
```

Exception example:

```
getEntityManager().createNativeQuery("SELECT MIN(start_date) FROM report")
  .setHint(QueryHints.HINT_CACHEABLE, true)
  .getSingleResult(); // IlligalStateException "aliases expected length is 0; actual length is 1".
```

QUESTION: How to cache a native SQL request?

Comment: try a solution / workaround described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25789176/aliases-expected-length-is-0-actual-length-is-1-on-hibernate-query-cache